Formula for power of a lens submerged in a medium
I was always of the opinion that the power of a lens would invariably be the reciprocal of its focal length, irrespective of the medium surrounding it. However, I ran into a slightly different formula after a school exam today: $P=n/f$ where $n$ is the absolute refractive index of the surrounding medium.
Is this the correct formula? If so, does the lens-maker formula just give us a value $1/f$, which is NOT the power of the lens?

Recall that if the lens is in a medium with the same index of refraction it is no longer a lens at all. Standard formulas are in air with $n=1$.

When the power of a single lens is defined as $P=\frac{1}{f}$, a quick modification of the lensmaker's equation for thin lenses yields the result you are asking about:
$$P=\frac{1}{f}=\frac{n_2-n_1}{n_1}\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2} \right) $$
Or:
$$P=\frac{n_1}{f}=(n_2-n_1)\left(\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2} \right) $$
Where $n_1$ is the surrounding medium index, $n_2$ is the lens medium index, $R_1$ and $R_2$ is the curvature of the first and second lens surfaces, respectively. Note that the units are still correct in diopters (1/m), since the refractive index carries no units.
I hope this helps.
Source: Introduction to Optics 3rd ed., Pedrotti, 2007

It sure helped! But I'm still unclear which of the formulae you have mentioned is the strictly correct one. Could you confirm?

I'm not sure what you mean by "strictly correct" -- they are both the lensmaker's equation, and yield the same answer for the focal length of the lens. I realize in hindsight that this answer is not completely clear, in that technically the second equation absorbs a factor of $n_1$ into P, which would have to be divided out to retrieve the first equation. I would say for the sake of clarity, always use the first equation I gave.
